# How to extract IP addresses from a list of strings using a regular expression?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm currently using MongoDB together with Elasticsearch (via River). A database entry(completely indexed as strings by Elasticsearch) looks like as follows:

```
{name: "My Name", source: "Google", values: ['value1', 'bla bla', 'This is an IP Address 127.0.0.1', 'another ip 192.168.0.1', 'this is a domain www.google.de', 'another nice domain http://stackoverflow.com']}
```

Now I want to write a regex query in NodeJS to get all the IP Addresses/domain names out of each entry. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you want `values` to be a stringified JSON array? It doesn't make much sense to index that into ES. Is there any way you could index a real array instead? By doing so, you could then have a specific analyzer in your index settings that does all that parsing job for you.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will change the question. Can you explain how to do it with the analyzer?